# PowerShell, call script with parameter without a value, like a script with options

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to call a PowerShell script with options? Like a parameter without a value.

For instance I currently use:

```
param (
    $lastmonth=0
);
```

in the script. Now I can use the call

```
script.ps1 -lastmonth 1
```

or

```
script.ps1
```

and use $lastmonth for controlling the flow.

But I'd like to have the calls like

```
script.ps1 -lastmonth
```

and

```
script.ps1
```

and control the flow depending on whether -lastmonth was given, or not.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Set the type of your parameter to `[switch]`, e.g.

```
param (
    [switch]$lastmonth
);
```

**EDIT**:
Note that the variable will be a boolean. You can test it like:

```
if ($lastMonth) {
    Write-Host "lastMonth is set."
}
else {
    Write-Host "lastMonth is not set."
}
```

(thanks Chris)

Comment: ... and then it's a boolean variable.

Comment: @Chris Lol, yep, should probably have mentioned that! I'll update my answer :)

Comment: It seems you have to explicitly use `$lastMonth.IsPresent` for unary conditions, as it is not a true boolean.  `if ($lastMonth)` works 
`$lastMonth?x:y` does not, but 
`$lastMonth.IsPresent?x:y` does.

PS 7.3.9

Answer (score 2):

This is called a *switch parameter*. Checkout out the [official documentation @ Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#switch-parameters).